# Best way to watch HDR video content on non-HDR monitor

Tags: video, video-player

Playing HDR video on a non-HDR system usually results in "washed out" colors and low contrast.

I read that "PotPlayer" offers a "HDR Correction" feature. However, I also read that the player shows ads.
If I understand it correctly it is also possible to install "K-Lite Codec Pack" and then select "madVR" as video renderer in the preferred player. - Is this a good solution?
Or maybe it is best to convert the video file before playing it?
What's the best way to do it?

And what about quality? Is a "corrected" HDR video on a non-HDR system the same quality as a corresponding SDR video?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that nowadays most players come with automatic HDR correction.

I tested VLC, mpv, MPC-HC (K-Lite) and Windows 10 "movies & tv" app with HEVC codec.

The "movies & tv" app works best. By far the best contrast and colors. I think the 99 cent for the HEVC codec are well spent.